# failed to build native extension for bcrypt-ruby gem under cygwin on windows xp

Tags: ruby, cygwin, rvm, bundler, bcrypt-ruby

I am setting up a testing agent on Windows XP for a Rails App.

To enforce consistency between Agents, I am installing it through Bundler with RVM with Cygwin.

The following is the result of running bundle install in the project directory(EDIT: Note that running gem install bcrypt-ruby produces identical output):

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /goBaltoEngineering/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
In file included from wrapper.c:27:0:
/goBaltoEngineering/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward/util.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/util.h" instead of bare     "util.h"
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.so
bcrypt_ext.o:bcrypt_ext.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `_ruby_bcrypt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:207: recipe for target `bcrypt_ext.so' failed
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /goBaltoEngineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@togo/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /goBaltoEngineering/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@togo/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

the cygwin gcc package is installed:

```
$ whereis gcc
gcc: /bin/gcc.exe /usr/bin/gcc.exe /lib/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /cygdrive/e/Cygwin/bin/gcc.exe /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz


$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3/configure    --srcdir=/gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.3-3/gcc4-4.5.3-3/src/gcc-4.5.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-  prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib -- datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --datarootdir=/usr/share -- docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc4 -C --datadir=/usr/share --infodir=/usr/share/info -- mandir=/usr/share/man -v --with-gmp=/usr --with-mpfr=/usr --enable-bootstrap --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-lto --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-symvers --enable-libjava --program-suffix=-4 --enable-libgomp --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-threads=posix --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-libgcj-sublibs CC=gcc-4 CXX=g++-4 CC_FOR_TARGET=gcc-4 CXX_FOR_TARGET=g++-4 GNATMAKE_FOR_TARGET=gnatmake GNATBIND_FOR_TARGET=gnatbind --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC)
```

as is bcrypt:

```
 $ whereis bcrypt
 bcrypt: /bin/bcrypt.exe /usr/bin/bcrypt.exe /cygdrive/e/Cygwin/bin/bcrypt.exe /usr/share/man/man1/bcrypt.1.gz

 bcrypt -v
 bcrypt: unknown option -- v
 Usage is: /bin/bcrypt -[orc][-sN] file1 file2..
   -o Write output to standard out
   -r Do NOT remove input files after processing
   -c Do NOT compress files before encryption
   -sN How many times to overwrite input files with random data
```

Results of further research:

Setting

```
        rvm use system
```

(in my case 1.9.3-p286) allows bcrypt-ruby to install without incident

Installing 1.9.3-p286 through rvm and setting

```
        rvm use 1.9.3-p286
```

Results in an identical (bar the ruby version) error message.

Installing on Mac OS X works without a hitch on numerous developer stations and several Mac Agents.

All of this suggests that the error is at the intersection of rvm with cygwin.

I have tried everything I could come up with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you should report your error to ruby team: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, why do you think this is a bug with ruby rather then say, with RVM/Cygwin/Bcrypt?

Thanks!

Comment: In either case I've reported it here:
http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dodged it the following way:
Install Rubyinstaller for my version of Ruby:

http://rubyinstaller.org/

Remove Cygwin from my Path (Right Click My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables).

Downloaded Git Bash and set up ssh by following the instructions here:

http://mrsimonelliott.com/blog/setting-git-and-github-windows-xp

Downloaded Ruby Installer DevKit

http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Downloaded QT

http://qt-project.org/downloads
(The mingw directory is within where I installed Git)

Added QT/bin to the Path.

I only get on version of Ruby but I suppose that when this becomes an issue, I can always use Pik.

I am fairly convinced this is an RVM issue by the way.